# Hover-Over Tooltip on Map of the United States

Tags: javascript, html, web, hover, tooltip

I would like to make a simple website that has a picture of the United States. When the user hovers their mouse over a particular state, I want to display a tooltip with information on that state.

The main problem I'm having is that I want the boundaries of the state to be obeyed. I do not want to have hidden rectangles overlayed on the state image, but rather I want the tooltip to be responsive to ***every state contour***.

What would be the most logical way to go about this? Does the type of image I use for the United States (bitmap-based vs. vector-based)?

Thank you for your help!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any browser limitation?? because if you use a SVG image you can easy detect which states has been click with javascript. But of course this is not Totally support it in older browsers...!!

You can make the SVG image with `Adobe illustrator` as example export the image as SVG, and consume it in you html as code (you should open the svg image with a text editor copy and paste the code) and from them you can define which areas you will click..

best

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 - use regular HTML with a regular bitmap image (probably png).  Use an imagemap with tooltips.  You can define circles, rectangles, polygons, whatever.  It's just easy HTML, no javascript, but the image is static.

Method 2 - use openlayers.org and define your areas using a gpx / kml file or similar.  This looks much fancier and you can zoom and pan and do all sorts of fancy things, including pretty HTML popups, but it requires much more work, including javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the html  tag to map your image and define each particular state area as a polygon shape with a set of points to interpolate the state contour. It would be a hell of an effort thought.

Answer (score -1):

You should use [this solution](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html).  It's already pretty much done for you.  Also check out [the docs](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/).

If you want to do something fancier with the mouseover, you could use [qtip2](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/), it works great.